# Java how to get file without full name

Tags: java, file

I need to get the file from directory which is downloaded from application in another part of app, but name of this file is creating dynamically. I mean that it is always `Query_` and then some digits, fe. `Query_21212121212`, `Query_22412221`. I need to get the absolute file path, sth like C:/dir/Query_*. How to do that?

Comment: are there more files with that name?

Comment: no, only one file

Comment: do you know the path? to the directory?

Comment: These links may help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#listdir and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#glob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the Path where the files reside, you can create a DirectoryStream and get all the files in it.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#glob

Example (from link above):

```
Path dir = ...;
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream =
     Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.{java,class,jar}")) { //<--- change the glob to 
                                                            //fit your name pattern.
    for (Path entry: stream) {
        System.out.println(entry.getFileName());
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    // IOException can never be thrown by the iteration.
    // In this snippet, it can // only be thrown by newDirectoryStream.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

About globs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob

So in your case it would probably be something like `"Query_*"`. Do you use a special extension or no extension at all? If it were .txt then the glob should be like `"Query_[0-9]+.txt"`.