# Check if file exists based on partial file name in Java

Tags: java, file

I opted to use the `isFile()` method from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java) thread which requires absolute path to the file.

```
boolean doesFileExist = new File("C:/downloads/MyFile.txt").isFile();
```

I have gotten Selenium and Robot class to save the text file to a local directory but the file name is dynamic: `MyTextFile_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.txt`. However, `MyTextFile_` always remains the same. I want to check just with a partial file name match.

What is an elegant way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272246/java-how-to-get-file-without-full-name?rq=1

Comment: Here you can find the solution to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752034/how-to-check-a-file-if-exists-with-wildcard-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code should help you.

> First list out all the files in the folder
>
> Start a loop and then get the fileName for each file and start
>   comparing the name to do your job.

```
String folderName = "."; // Give your folderName
File[] listFiles = new File(folderName).listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {

    if (listFiles[i].isFile()) {
        String fileName = listFiles[i].getName();
        if (fileName.startsWith("MyTextFile_")
                && fileName.endsWith(".txt")) {
            System.out.println("found file" + " " + fileName);
        }
    }
}
```